# Magento | Cannot reindex

Tags: php, sql, magento, reindex

Anytime I try to reindex in Magento CE 1.8.1, I get an error message saying "There was a problem with reindexing process."

I've seen various solutions online that use some SQL queries, however, I don't have DB access, just file access (I know, huge pain).

I've also tried the approach using the reindex.php script in the root directory, but that just results in a 404 page when I do to it.

Furthermore, for some reason this instance was setup without the /shell directory.

Any advice?